# Oracle Update row with minimum value

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to give kind of unique random code to users but without skipping any number in range. My table is like this

```
RandomCode | IsUsed | RNum
--------------------------
002        | Y      | 1
004        | Y      | 2
003        | NULL   | 3
005        | Y      | 4
001        | NULL   | 5
```

So next randomcode to use should be 003 and then 001. The problem is user can return the code and i should give that number to someonelse. In that case I'm setting IsUsed to NULL.

I've tried selecting the minimum Rnum with IsUsed column to be NULL. and then updading the table. But encountered Race condition and users got duplicate RandomCode.

Any help to

UPDATE TABLE
SET IsUsed = N'Y'
WHERE IsUsed = NULL and RNum = MIN(RNUM)
RETURNING

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made two little mistakes in your code:

1. You did `IsUsed = NULL`.

   This condition always returns false. Nothing equates to `NULL`. Use `IsUsed IS NULL` instead.
2. You used `RNum = MIN(RNum)`. Use a subquery instead.

Here's your query with these simple modifications.

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET IsUsed = N'Y'
WHERE IsUsed IS NULL
and RNum = (SELECT MIN(RNum) FROM table WHERE IsUsed IS NULL)
```

Comment: Does it cause database LOCK?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself and load test your query? That way, your concepts will get clearer and you will learn a lot of other things. Me commenting on this would not be the correct thing to do for me. :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment rachcha. But I think it's causing race issue.

Comment: You think; you don't know for sure!

Comment: I think it's just a problem of your workflow. I will give a detailed answer. Please allow me some time. Also edit your question and add some more sample data to make things clearer.